# Same age with me vs Same age as me

Tags: prepositions

> - She is same age with me.
> - She is same age as me.

So, is it right to say that 'she is same age' when I want say that 'her age is same with mine'?
And among 'with me' and 'as me' which is the grammatically right expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct expression is 'She is the same age as me.' To say 'the same age with me' will certainly raise quite a few eyebrows among native speakers. 'As' is the conjunction you need to use to indicate the comparison. Actually, to be a stickler, the most correct way to express your sentence would be 'She is the same age as I AM'.

Hope it helped.

Comment: It's more common to say "she's as old as me", right?

Comment: In some cases yes. I think the difference is in the emphasis. You would say 'she's as old as me' if she is often mistakened to be younger.

Comment: Then, what's the correct way to say that expression grammatically? I think it should be "she's the same age as I", although it doesn't sound good because of "I". And I want to know, if my assumption is correct, whether to say "she's the same age as me" could be grammatically acceptable.

Comment: @SIS, 'She is the same age as I' is grammatical, but sounds stilted because it's overly formal in most contexts it'd be used in. 'She is the same age as me' is more common in everyday language. Alternatively, you could also say 'She and I are the same age' or ' We are both the same age'.

Comment: i think I can also use “like me”, though it is informal.

Comment: @John V,  I definitely wouldn't use 'like' in place of 'as' here because the proper English construction is 'same as'. It's different from cases where 'like' is accepted as an informal/colloquial substitute for 'as' e.g. He can't play cricket like he used to (which, strictly speaking should've been 'as he used to').

Answer (score 2):

> She is the same age **as** me.

It is a comparative statement.